# Accessing the information contained in the .webtestResult files in code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, webtest

I'd like to programmatically retrieve information related to test results. After a test run, I want to go through the test results and, for each test failed, to get the name of the failed test, the reason why it failed (validation rule message or extraction rule message) and the value of one key contained in the test context.

I couldn't find anything that I can use on how to dig into trx and webtestResult files. Does anyone have any hints for me?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 2):

After searching a bit more I came upon this:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/slumley/2009/11/11/vsts-2010-feature-api-for-processing-web-test-results/

The RequestResult property returns a WebTestRequestResult object, which exposes 2 properties, ValidationRuleResults and     ExtractionRuleResults, through which the needed information can be retrieved.

Comment: having gone through that blog, I realized that what I've been looking for is more close to what you were trying to do other than what the blog is doing.   Care to share your code, say on http://pastebin.com/, etc please?  It doesn't have to be your latest and greatest, your first trial code that went through would be fine.  I can ask in a new question if you prefer. TIA!